# XPS polystyrene foam board insulation & Spar Urethane

Tags: insulation

Will xps polystyrene foam board insulation react with wood that is coated with spar urethane? Will the foam board melt?

Answer (score 1):

You should check with the manufacturer of the foam board for a definitive answer, but I can't imagine any circumstance where styrofoam would interact badly with a cured finish. (Urethane is pretty inert when dry.)